# $\sum a_n$ is a series of positive terms such that $\lim _{n\to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=l$

Tags: real-analysis

if $\sum a_n$ is a series of positive terms such that  $\lim _{n\to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=l$

Then

(A)if $l<1 $ then$(a_n)$ is increasing sequence

(B) if $l>1$ the $(a_n)$ is decreasing sequence

im trying like this

since  $\lim _{n\to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=l$

then $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n|}-l|<\epsilon \forall n\ge m$

then $l-\epsilon \le\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<l+\epsilon  $ ......from here ?

Comment: See http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-ratio-test-for-sequence-convergence

Comment: @RobertZ... there is not they prove increasing or decresing

Comment: I think you're missing your conclusion (that the series converges/diverges given some criterion). But that's a good start. You might want to choose $\epsilon$ so that $l+\epsilon<1$ for one case. Is that enough of a hint?

Comment: In (A) it should be "eventually decreasing", in (B) it should be "eventually increasing".

Comment: Choose $ \epsilon $ such that $\epsilon \lt \vert 1 - l \vert$.  What conclusion can you draw about $a_n$ for $n \gt m$?

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $l<1$ then we can show that $\{a_n\}_n $ is **eventually** decreasing (and not that it is always decreasing).

Take $\epsilon=1-l>0$. Then there is some $m$ such that for all $n\geq m$,
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<l+\epsilon=1$$
So $\{a_n\}_n $ is positive and **eventually** decreasing.

Note that the above property implies that $\{a_n\}_n $ has a limit $L=\inf_{n\geq m}a_n\geq 0$. Now if $L>0$ then 
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\to \frac{L}{L}=1>l$$
and we have a contradiction. Hence $L=0$ and $a_n\to 0$.

Now try to show the case $l>1$.